# How can I calculate correlation between different values of a python dictionary?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am learning python.I want to calculate correlation between values.Below is my data which is a dictionary.

```
My_data = {1: [1450.0, -80.0, 840.0, -220.0, 630.0, 780.0, -1140.0], 2: [1450.0, -80.0, 840.0, -220.0, 630.0, 780.0, -1140.0],3:[ 720.0, -230.0, 460.0, 220.0, 710.0, -460.0, 90.0] }
```

This is what I expect to have in return.

```
    1     2      3
1   1     0.69  0.77
2         1     0.54
3               1
```

This is the code I tried. I get TypeError:unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'long'
I am not sure what went wrong. I would appreciate if somebody explains me and help me get the desired solution.

```
my_array=np.array(My_data .values())
Correlation = np.corrcoef(my_array,my_array)
```

Comment: So, all keys have equal number of elements in their lists?

Comment: Yes, that is true. @ Divakar

Answer (score 1):

#### Case 1: if you are open to use pandas

Using pandas (which is a wrapper of numpy), you can porceed as follows:

```
In [55]: import pandas as pd

In [56]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(My_data, orient='index').T

In [57]: df.corr(method='pearson')
Out[57]: 
          1         2         3
1  1.000000  1.000000  0.384781
2  1.000000  1.000000  0.121978
3  0.384781  0.121978  1.000000

In [58]: df.corr(method='kendall')
Out[58]: 
          1         2         3
1  1.000000  1.000000  0.333333
2  1.000000  1.000000  0.240385
3  0.333333  0.240385  1.000000

In [59]: df.corr(method='spearman')
Out[59]: 
          1        2         3
1  1.000000  1.00000  0.464286
2  1.000000  1.00000  0.327370
3  0.464286  0.32737  1.000000

In [60]:
```

---

#### Explanation:

The following line creates a `pandas.DataFrame` from the dictionary `My_data`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(My_data, orient='index').T
```

Which looks like this:

```
In [60]: df
Out[60]: 
         1       2       3
0   1450.0  1450.0   720.0
1    -80.0   -80.0  -230.0
2    840.0   840.0   460.0
3   -220.0  -220.0   220.0
4    630.0   630.0   710.0
5    780.0   780.0  -460.0
6  -1140.0 -1140.0    90.0
7      NaN   450.0  -640.0
8      NaN   730.0   870.0
9      NaN  -810.0  -290.0
10     NaN   390.0 -2180.0
11     NaN  -220.0  -790.0
12     NaN -1640.0    65.0
13     NaN  -590.0    70.0
14     NaN  -145.0   460.0
15     NaN  -420.0     NaN
16     NaN   620.0     NaN
17     NaN   450.0     NaN
18     NaN   -90.0     NaN
19     NaN   990.0     NaN
20     NaN  -705.0     NaN
```

then `df.corr()` will compute the pairwise correlation between columns.

---

#### Case 2: if you want a pure numpy solution

You need to convert your data into numpy.ndarray first, then you can compute the correlation like this,

```
In [91]: np.corrcoef(np.asarray(new_data.values()))
Out[91]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  1.        ,  0.38478131],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  0.38478131],
       [ 0.38478131,  0.38478131,  1.        ]])

In [92]:
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do in numpy array instead of pandas?

Comment: @A.S to use np.corrcoef the lists must have equal length as described in the doc https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html

Comment: are you referring to list of values of dictionary when you say lists must be equal length? If so, the list of each values would always be same length. It is just that when I pasted here i delete some items so it won't take much space.

Comment: @A.S, yes I am referring to that, please share an example with equal length.

Comment: I edited my question. Now, the list of values are of equal length. Thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: @ MedAli, I tried case 2 example. I get following error:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'long'

Comment: @ MedAli, I think my length were not same again which caused the error. Thank you very much for your help. Both cases (examples) are extremely helpful for me to understand data frame and array operations.